# How to pass one PHP file data in received response PHP file in Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

File "addProduct.php" which contains form,where "brand" obtained after selecting "category" field by help of external php file "getBrand.php",Where in brand HTML as below,

```
<select name="brand" id="brand">

</select>
```

but on edit time,How to display,the Selected option value in brand dropdown list & How to pass `$listEdit[0]['product_brandID']`, in external response php file, where

```
<option value="<?php echo $brandID;?>">
     <?php echo $brandID;?> 
</option>
```

So I want to pass `$listEdit[0]['product_brandID']` of "add_Product.php" file in external file "getBrand.php", where inside `<option>` to check below condition,

```
<?php if($listEdit[0]['product_brandID']==$result_brand[$j]['brand_id']){echo "selected";}?>
```

inside `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same by this way..
generate the *brand* dropdown value by using query of brand table 
and check with the value which you stored in database then you can use like this.

     `if($listEdit[0]['product_brandID']==$result_brand[$j]['brand_id']){echo "selected";}`

Comment: yes manoj,But on Edit time selected products ID obtained in "addProduct.php" & from that ID, I also got BrandID,But now how to pass that BrandID into "getBrand.php",to check selected condition of <option>

Comment: Yes,I know But hoe to pass that database value in other getBrand.php file,Because there is Brand dropdown Value,so once id will pass there in getBrand.php then I can check,so main problem is How to pass that ID to getBrand.php